# How to merge array of object containing same id

Tags: javascript

I have one array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    val: 5
  },
  {
    id:1,
    val: 5
  },
  {
    id:2,
    val: 6
  },
  {
    id:2,
    val: 7
  }
]
```

and I want something like this

```
[
  {
    id:1,
    val: 10
  },
  {
    id:2,
    val: 13
  },
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use the `reduce` method. This is really easy once you read up on it.

Comment: Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/oc7gtLs9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var t=[
  {
    id:1,
    val: 5
  },
  {
    id:1,
    val: 5
  },
  {
    id:2,
    val: 6
  },
  {
    id:2,
    val: 7
  }
]

t.reduce((acc,elem)=>{
    if(acc.filter((elemi)=>elemi.id==elem.id)[0])acc.filter((elemi)=>elemi.id==elem.id)[0].val+=elem.val;
    else acc.push(elem);
    return acc
}
,[])
```